# Menus wont fully show in my website.

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, dropdown

I had to make a website for my school project and i did but there is an issue. My navigation bar has menus that drop down when you click the link and also has it so the bar when touches the top becomes sticky however when i scroll down the menu is cut short and can hardly be seen. It can be seen in this https://gyazo.com/4549278923f72e383f8fbbda0ddb0a2d .

```
#navbar {
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:1080px;
 background-color:rgb(235,0,0);
 font-family: "montserrat";
 padding-left: 470px;
 height: 70px;
 margin-left: -8px;
}
.text{
  color:white;
  padding-left:50px;
  float:left
}
.mySlides {display:none;}
.middle{
  margin: -10;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
}
.menu {
    float: left;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-family: montserrat;
    font-size: 16px;  
}
.menu2 .button {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 60px;
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-family: montserrat;  
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: inherit;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow:rgb(100,0,0);
    z-index: 1;
} 
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: visible;
}
.show {
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
}
.sticky{
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
  padding-top:60px;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onscroll="stickyBar()">
<div id="homejump">
<img src="Logomakr_9xaA4u.png" alt="Logo" style="width:28%; height:25%; padding-left:35%; padding-right:35%; overflow: hidden;">
</div>
<div id="navbar"><div class="menu">
<a href="#homejump" style="color: white;text-decoration: none;">Home</a></div>
<div class="menu"><div class="menu2">
<button class="button" onclick="mental()">Mental Health
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a></div></div></div>
      <div class="menu"><div class="menu2">
    <button class="button" onclick="physical()">Physical Health
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown1">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a></div></div></div>
      <div class="menu"><div class="menu2">
    <button class="button" onclick="rehab()">Rehab
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown2">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a></div></div></div>
</div>
 <script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();
function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 7000);
}
 function mental() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
 function physical() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
}
 function rehab() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;  
function stickyBar() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) 
     {navbar.classList.add("sticky");}
     else {navbar.classList.remove("sticky");}
}
</script>
```

This is all the code for the menu as well as to make the bar sticky. How do i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your #navbar is 70px of height and has overflow:hidden value, that's why you don't see more

Comment: as for the "Sticky" nav use position:fixed for the #navbar

Comment: Thank You. I knew it was something small but im just too nooby to find it out.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome :) If I helped please mark this answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

It is the way you manage your variables. In the `stickyBar` function call, the `navbar` variable is not not known (not in the function scope). You have to get it in the function or use a parametered function.

Example of solution:

```
function stickyBar() {

 var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

 if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) 
 {navbar.classList.add("sticky");}
 else {navbar.classList.remove("sticky");}
}
```